# Base Layer of Web App that Uses .NET Core and Angular 2/4

Tags: asp.net, yeoman

Hello I am am looking for instructions using yeoman app generator or a template of the minimal amount of code to create a web application that integrates both Entity Framework Core and Angular 2/4.

Preferably the answer provided would use the yeoman app generator. Also I do not mind installing any other necessary tools to achieve this objective.

Comment: Not sure why this is frowned upon. Willing to put another 50 points of my reputation down for an answer

Comment: I don't know about yeoman, but for ASP.NET Core, Angular2 and WebPack, [this template](https://github.com/FabianGosebrink/ASPNETCore-Angular-Webpack-StarterTemplate) got me started and works well. I also added Mads Kristensen's [NPM Task Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.NPMTaskRunner) extension to Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. Will spend some time using the template and if it works the bounty is yours. Fyi tho the template is fairly long so it may take me a day or two to complete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far, I haven't find yeomen generator for all three packages - ASP.Net Core, Entity Framework Core and Angular.

However, there is an official generator template [aspnetcore-spa](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices#user-content-creating-new-applications) for ASP.Net Core and Angular. ***Note: current generator is updated to Angular 4, although it said 2.***

- npm install -g yo generator-aspnetcore-spa
- cd some-empty-directory
- yo aspnetcore-spa

[image]

***NOTE***: It requires [dotnet SDK version 1.0.0 or later](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core). If you have old version, it'll prompt you to update your dotnet SDK first when you run `yo aspnetcore-spa`.

### YouTube Video

[ASP.NET Core for Angular, React, Knockout etc developers - Steve Sanderson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6MPSLgsGGs)

Comment: Wow this looks like it addresses my needs perfectly! Give me some time to make it work with my machine. If it does the bounty is yours

Comment: This is amazing. Saved me a lot of headache by setting the environment up manually. Thank you!

Comment: You're quite welcome. I'm also looking for official yeoman generator for all three - ASP.Net Core, Entity Framework Core and Angular 2. Hopefully, we'll see that in the future.